# Sitecore 7.2 Update3 $name Issue

Tags: sitecore

We are facing one issue in Sitecore 7.2 Update 3.
Sitecore.Context.Item is returning old version and that version is not available in web DB, so we are getting $name for all the fields. On page load $name is displaying, if I refresh the page then it works fine after 5 minutes again we are getting $name, let me know if any body face this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been addressed since **Sitecore CMS and DMS 7.2 rev.151021 (7.2 Update-5)**:

- `Obsolete item versions might be present in search indexes after publishing. This has been fixed. (440383)`

[See the release notes on SDN](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC72.aspx) for more information about the changes.

Additionally, check the known issue article with a possible workaround:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/992608

Answer (score 0):

We fixed the issue by making sure that `sitecore` was returning the latest version of the context.  We found out that `sitecore`, for some reason, was looking for a version on the web DB, and this was not the latest version.  So we applied this:

Before:

```
public virtual Item Item
{
    get { return Context.Item; }
}
```

After:

```
public virtual Item Item
{
    get { return Context.Item.Versions.GetLatestVersion(); }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maby something with a language version.
put the language code in the URL to ensure that you do not change the language, or check the Sitecore language cookie.

Other thing to check, In IIS check the Application pool, Advanced Settings, Maximum Worker Processes set it to 1 to ensure there is only 1 worker which should give every time the same response.